# LaTeX Error: Environment Appendices undefined

Tags: appendices

Please, can you help me to solve this appendix problem.
Here's the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article} 
% for 2-column layout use \documentclass[USenglish,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             %(only for the pdftex engine)
%\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}[2017/03/31]%(only for the luatex or the xetex engine)
\usepackage[big,online]{dgruyter}   %values: small,big | online,print,work
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsgen,theorem,graphicx,epsfig}
\usepackage[numbers,square,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}

Power system oscillations’ behavior is a dominant thought in the power system stability discipline\cite{Perez-Londono:2012,Munoz:2011}.

all data are well mentioned in \ref{secA1}

\begin{Appendices}
\section{}\label{secA1}
\noindent \textbf{\underbar{A.1. Multimachine power system parameters}}\underbar{:}

\noindent \textbf{\underbar{}}

\noindent \textbf{Generator1:  }Power, voltage and frequency ratings [100MVA, 16.5kV, 60Hz]. ra=0 p.u, xl=0 p.u, Xd, X'd, X"d [0.1460p.u, 0.0608p.u,  0 p.u], T'd0 and T"d0 [8.98s, 0.0s], Xq, X'q, X"q [0.0969 p.u, 0.0969 p.u, 0.00p.u.],  T'q0 and T"q0 [0.31s, 0.00s] Inertia (M = 2H) and Damping [2*23.64s, 0.00p.u.], Kw and Kp [0.0p.u., 0.0p.u.].
\noindent \textbf{} \newline
\end{Appendices}



\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{Perez-Londono:2012}
\href{https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6319119}{S. Pérez-Londoño, L. Rodríguez-García, Y. U. López.  Effects of doubly fed wind generators on voltage stability of power systems. In \emph{2012 Sixth IEEE/PES Transmission and Distribution: Latin America Conference and Exposition (T{\&}D-LA)}; 2012; Montevideo, Uruguay: pp. 1-6. doi: 10.1109/TDC-LA.2012.6319119}

\bibitem{Munoz:2011}
\href{https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5772545}{J. C. Muñoz, C. A. Cañizares. Comparative stability analysis of DFIG-based wind farms and conventional synchronous generators. In \emph{2011 IEEE/PES Power Systems Conference and Exposition, PSCE} 2011; Phoenix, AZ, USA: pp. 1-7. doi: 10.1109/PSCE.2011.5772545}

\end{thebibliography}
%\end{Appendices}
\end{document}
```

Here are also the sytle files if needed https://file.fm/u/gd4cvpeez .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `\begin{appendix} ...  \end{appendix}`

Comment: Not related but you need to load `\usepackage{hyperref}` (now missing, for the `\href`) and then `\usepackage{cleveref}` just before `\begin{document}`

Comment: @SimonDispa, the prolem is solved. BIG THANKS